# Under what conditions is $\sup(A)$ not an accumulation point for $A$? $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I am having a hard time conceptualizing this question. I can't see any conditions that would make it soI couldn't find an accumulation point.

If $m = \sup(A)$, then can't we always find some $\alpha$; where $m - \epsilon < \alpha < m + \epsilon;\,\epsilon > 0$ that will intersect set $A$? Thus making it an accumulation point?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: If $m$ is an *isolated* point of $A$, it will be the only element of $A$ in some neighbourhood $(m-\varepsilon, m+\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if the set $A$ is finite, then it has no accumulation points (using the usual topology).

Answer (score 2):

The set $$(\frac{1}{n})$$ with $n\ge 1$ has supremum $1$. But $1$ is not an accumulation point because only one member of the sequence is in the interval $[0.9,1.1]$, for example. $0$ is an accumulation point because for every $\epsilon>0$, infinite many members of the sequence are in the interval $[0,\epsilon]$.

In general : $a$ is an accumulation point of a sequence, if for every $\epsilon>0$, infinite many members of the sequence are in the interval $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$.

The supremum is the smallest number $x$, such that no member of the sequence exceeds $x$.

Comment: In general this is true for any convergent sequence whose limit is not the supremum.